# Retrieve value of dynamic textbox from child directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a custom directive in angularjs that has a child directive. The child directive is responsible for generating dynamic input elements such as textboxes, radio button and checkbox which all have certain default values that are populated from an array. My need to is to retrieve the values of the dynamically created input elements.

```
      for (i = 0; i < scope.arr.length; i++) {

            if (scope.arr[i].type == "input" && scope.arr[i].value) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('form-block'))
                    .append($compile("<div>" + "</br>" + scope.arr[i].name + "</br>" + "<input type='text' ng-model='model[\"" + scope.arr[i].name + "\"]'/></div>")(scope));
            } else if (scope.arr[i].type == "password" && scope.arr[i].value) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('form-block'))
                    .append($compile("<div>" + "</br>" + scope.arr[i].name + "</br>" + "<input type='password' ng-model='model[\"" + scope.arr[i].name + "\"]'/></div>")(scope));

            } else if (scope.arr[i].type == "checkbox" && scope.arr[i].value) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('form-block'))
                    .append($compile("<div>" + "</br>" + scope.arr[i].name + "</br>" + "<input type='checkbox' ng-model='model[\"" + scope.arr[i].name + "\"]'/></div>")(scope));

            } else if (scope.arr[i].type == "radio" && scope.arr[i].value) {
                angular.element(document.getElementById('form-block'))
                    .append($compile("<div>" + "</br>" + scope.arr[i].name + "</br>" + "<input type='radio' value='" + scope.arr[i].value + "'" + "ng-model='model[\"" + scope.arr[i].name + "\"]'/></div>")(scope));
            }
        }
```

Following is the link of the fiddle to my code,

https://jsfiddle.net/f5r7onko/

I have tried multiple combinations, but I am not able to retrieve the values. Any ideas or suggestions would of immense help to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can directly access the value using models. Here is the updated jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f5r7onko/1/

eg. in HTML you can access like this

```
<p>textbox1 value = {{model.Textbox1}}</p>
<p>textbox2 value = {{model.Textbox2}}</p>
<p>textbox3 value = {{model.samplePassword}}</p>
```